# I need a jQuery custom validator with custom error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I am using VS 2010 with MVC 3 and unobtrusive validation. I am attempting to create a custom range validator to includes warnings where input values are acceptable but unexpected. (I have working functionality to submit the values with wanings by using the `ignore` option of the form validator)

The unobtrusive component is:

```
// The adapter to support ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive validation // 
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('rangewithwarning', ['min', 'max', 'wmin', 'wmax', 'warning'],
function (options) {
    options.rules['rangewithwarning'] = {
        min: options.params.min,
        max: options.params.max,
        wmin: options.params.wmin,
        wmax: options.params.wmax,
        warning: options.params.warning
    };
    options.messages['rangewithwarning'] = options.message;
});
```

I have Googled extensively on dynamic error messages which seem to come down to three methods but none of these allow me to display the optional error message. These are:

1. Returning the error message

   ```
   // The validator function
   $.validator.addMethod('rangewithwarning', function (value, element, params) {
   if (!value) {
       return true; // not testing 'is required' here!
   }
   var intValue = parseInt(value);
   // set logic here
   if (intValue >= params.wmin && intValue <= params.wmax) {
       // OK within both actual and range warning
       return true;
   }
   if (params.min <= intValue && intValue <= params.max) {
       //  outside warning but within allowed range - show warning
       return params.warning;
   }
   return $.validator.messages.rangewithwarning;
   ```

   });
2. Use showErrors

   ```
   // The validator function
   $.validator.addMethod('rangewithwarning', function (value, element, params) {
   if (!value) {
       return true; // not testing 'is required' here!
   }
   var validator = this;
   var intValue = parseInt(value);
   // set logic here
   if (intValue >= params.wmin && intValue <= params.wmax) {
       // OK within both actual and range warning
       return true;
   }

   if (params.min <= intValue && intValue <= params.max) {
       //  outside warning but within allowed range - show warning
       var errors = new Object();
       errors[element.name] = params.warning;
       validator.showErrors(errors);            
   }

   return false;
   });
   ```
3. Return an additional parameter from a `messager` function

None of these worked although when stepping through the second one the optional message was shown briefly then overwritten.

I'm clearly missing something obvious but cannot see what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A further thought - is it possible to have multiple validators on a field. In that case this could be split into a range validator and a custom rangewarning validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution which was to use the standard range attribute and then follow it with my new warn only attribute

```
(function ($) {

// The validator function
$.validator.addMethod('rangewarning', function (value, element, params) {
    var localElement = $(element);
    localElement.siblings("span").removeClass("warningOnlyDataOK")
    localElement.removeClass("warningOnlyDataOK")
    if (!value) {
        return true; // not testing 'is required' here!
    }
    var intValue = parseInt(value);
    // set logic here
    if (intValue >= params.wmin && intValue <= params.wmax) {
        // OK within both actual and range warning
        return true;
    }
    //  set display and ignore class items here etc
    localElement.siblings("span").addClass("warningOnlyDataOK")
    localElement.addClass("warningOnlyDataOK")
    return false;
});

// The adapter to support ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive validation // 
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('rangewarning', ['wmin', 'wmax'],
function (options) {
    options.rules['rangewarning'] = {
        wmin: options.params.wmin,
        wmax: options.params.wmax
    };
    options.messages['rangewarning'] = options.message;
});

} (jQuery));
```

Where the class `warningOnlyDataOK` is used to both display a different style error message and to ignore that validation on save.